# PHP inserting the type datetime into sql

Tags: php, sql

I have made a sql row as type: datetime.

The input for datetime should be like: `2013-02-02 10:13:20`

You get the drill like: `0000-00-00 00:00:00`

Now In php I use `date("Y-m-d H:i:s");`(current date and time) to insert it into my database. There are other variables as well. Those variables get inserted,but the datetime row stays: `0000-00-00 00:00:00`

I first got this code when everything except the date worked:

```
$resultaat = $mysqli2->query("INSERT INTO questions  (title, description, username, date_made) VALUES ('" . $title . "','" . $description . "', '".$username ."','".date("Y-m-d H:i:s")."')");
```

but all the information in the databases will get `""` around them.(Which could have caused the date to jump to  `0000-00-00 00:00:00`

Now when I try to insert again with other information, it wont even insert anymore. My problems:

- What is the real problem for the date to set to `0000-00-00 00:00:00`? Is it the automatic `""`?
- If it is the `""`, how can I lose them?

**EDIT:**

Nvm I lost the `""` It wasn't the problem that cause the insert to fail at the second try.
 - Why wont it insert in it anymore after I inserted once?

Now these aren't really different questions because it's about the same problem but here's my code and yes I know SQL Injection, I'll fix it later:

```
if (isset($_POST['title'])) {
$alles_goed=true;
$description=$_POST['description'];
$title=$_POST['title'];
$username=$_SESSION['username'];

if ($title=''){ 
$alles_goed=false;
echo'title is empty';
}

if($alles_goed==true){
    $resultaat = $mysqli2->query("INSERT INTO questions  (title, description, username, date_made) VALUES ('" . $title . "','" . $description . "', '".$username ."','".date("Y-m-d H:i:s")."')");

}
}
```

Comment: Print final SQL query. Then see if the value if correct.

Comment: Store date("Y-m-d H:i:s") value in a variable and assign to it and check whether it is inserting

Comment: @SaranyaSadhasivam still not inserting

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this:

```
$a=date("Y-m-d H:i:s");
if (!$resultaat = $mysqli2->query("INSERT INTO questions  (title, description, username, date_made) VALUES ('$title','$description','$username','$a')"))
{
   printf("Errormessage: %s\n", $mysqli2->error);
   exit;
}
```

and check if there is any error produced.

As to why is inserting it only once, you might have unique field.

Comment: I really have no idea what fixed it but when I did this. (Btw you forgot the "") it worked, but I already tried to put the date("y-m-d h:i:s") in a variable. I think I fixed it myself but I dont know how.

Comment: Where did I forgot "" ?

Comment: VALUES ('" . $title . "','" . $description . "', '".$username ."','".$a."')"

Comment: I didn't. My query is perfectly legal without "". Try it yourself.

Comment: In PHP, you can put variable inside double quotes. Try it for yourself.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/38082/discussion-between-sskoko-and-loko)

Comment: Please never use this code in production. Use [prepared statements](https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_prepared_statements.asp) instead to prevent [SQL Injection](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_injection.asp)

Comment: Not correct, mysqli is perfectly fine in preventing SQL Injection.

Answer (score 5):

Just use a **`now()`** on MySQL

```
$resultaat = $mysqli2->query("INSERT INTO questions  (title, description, username, date_made) VALUES ('" . $title . "','" . $description . "', '".$username ."',now()");
```